# Safe Markup for Dynamic Insertions Based Upon User Input

Tags: html, dynamic, markup

Is there any tag that allows safe markup? For instance:

```
<safe>[User input goes here]</safe>
```

I'm looking to utilize user input or dynamically populated content and would like a certain section to be wrapped in a tag which will not allow malicious code, however that is decided by standards committees.

Comment: If you're outputting content laced with user input, you require your server to sanitize your content, not the client browser. There's no such tag, and if there were, it would be broken if the user content included the ending tag. For example, `<safe>Input </safe> malicious content </safe>`.

Comment: Alright, but wouldn't something like string.Replace('</safe>', ''); string = '<safe restriction="string">' + string + '</safe>'; be a lot better than filtering out a bunch of content? Also, could the browser not verify security tags that are not closed, and disable the content in question?

Comment: There's no tag that ignores html within in to begin with, so the replace method wouldn't work. Also, the browser is not responsible for detecting the proper closing of tags. If you're using PHP, the best method is to `echo htmlspecialchars($user_input, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` this will not filter the user input, it will convert the html characters into their html equivalent (ex. `<` into `&lt;`). That is better than trying to filter content.

Comment: Looks like that method is working, with the exception that it will not allow different levels of "Safeness". In particular, the ability to let users insert html to display links, but not execute code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such HTML element that does that.

The sanitization is best handled on the server side.